# Unable to upgrade

Tags: upgrade

When I tried to upgrade,  Getting the following error:

```
Your current Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is going out of support on 2014-08-07.  After this date security updates for critical parts (kernel and graphics stack) of your system will no longer be available.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-trusty: Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-trusty (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.1~precise1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                        Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.3-2build1 is to be installed
xserver-xorg-lts-trusty: Depends: xserver-xorg-core-lts-trusty (>= 2:1.11) but 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2~precise1 is to be installed
```

Comment: how did you tried to upgrade ?

Comment: From Update manager

Answer (score 0):

the best solution its upgrading your LTS, i was wondering about this since june, the codes that i used were:

> sudo do-release-upgrade
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo update-manager -d

try it and then tell us if works!!!
,Good luck!

Comment: Hi,here is the output based on what you requested.

Comment: Hi,here is the output based on what you requested.
It gave a bunch of messages...but post reboot it seems to be OK. Im not clear on how to paste the messages for review. But thanks a ton for your help